# str_replace not work

Tags: php, str-replace

This is my string:

```
$a = "RSS
here: 
Your result: 3 points form 50 example.";
```

How to delete "RSS here:" from this string?

My try:

```
$result = str_replace("RSS
here: 
Your result: 3 points form 50 example.", " " ,$a);
echo $result;
```

Comment: do you have linefeeds in your text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\r\n` for `carriage return + line feed` eg new line:

```
$a = "RSS
here: 
Your result: 3 points form 50 example.";

$result = str_replace("RSS\r\nhere:", "" ,$a);
echo $result;
```

**Result:**

```
Your result: 3 points form 50 example.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not have special characters in the RSS here: this should do

```
$result = str_replace("RSS here:", "", $a);
```